# 'CSRF Token is missing' in Flask but it *is* rendering in the template

Tags: python, flask, csrf, flask-wtforms

**The Problem**

When I try to login (using Flask-login) I get `Bad Request The CSRF session token is missing` but the token is rendering (in the template), secret_key is set, and I'm running locally at `localhost:5000`.

When I was able to log in, I could no longer use my Flask-WTF forms for the same reason. By calling `form.validate()` on the route, I got `CSRF token missing` for all of the forms. Effectively the forms just did nothing. If I look in the template where I call `{{form.hidden_tag()}}` the CSRF token is as below:

```
<input id="csrf_token" name="csrf_token" type="hidden" value="sdfksdognslkdgnskldgjsd.Xh897A.i_changed_this_just_in_case">
```

**The config**

My app is initialised via an app factory in `__init.py__`

```
def create_app(config=BaseConfig):
    # Initialise the Flask app
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object(config)
    initialise_extensions(app)
    register_template_filters(app)
    app.register_blueprint(core)
    register_shell_context(app)

    return app

def initialise_extensions(app):
    # Since the application instance is now created, pass it to each Flask
    # extension instance to bind it to the Flask application instance (app)
    db.init_app(app)
    migrate.init_app(app, db)
    csrf.init_app(app)
    # Login
    login.init_app(app)
    login.login_view = 'core.login'

class BaseConfig(object):
    SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get('SECRET_KEY')
    FLASK_DEBUG = os.environ.get('FLASK_DEBUG')
    DB_NAME = os.environ.get('DB_NAME')
    DB_USER = os.environ.get('DB_USER')
    DB_PASS = os.environ.get('DB_PASS')
    DB_SERVICE = os.environ.get('DB_SERVICE')
    DB_PORT = os.environ.get('DB_PORT')
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = 'postgresql://{0}:{1}@{2}:{3}/{4}'.format(
        DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_SERVICE, DB_PORT, DB_NAME
    )
    SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS = True
    BOT_TOKEN = ''
    WTF_CSRF_ENABLED = True
    SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True
    # WTF_CSRF_SECRET_KEY = 'secret #This makes no difference regardless if its set or not.
```

**Extensions.py**

```
import os
from flask_marshmallow import Marshmallow
from flask_migrate import Migrate
from flask_login import LoginManager
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet
import redis
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_wtf.csrf import CSRFProtect

# Initialise basics
db = SQLAlchemy()

# Sort Migrate out
migrate = Migrate(compare_type=True)

# Initialise Marshmallow
ma = Marshmallow()

# Get cryptography
en = Fernet(os.getenv('ENV').encode())

# CSRF protect
csrf = CSRFProtect()

# use Flask-Login extension for login forms
login = LoginManager()
login.login_view = 'login'

# Initialise redis
redis_host = os.getenv('REDIS_DB')
rdb = redis.Redis(host=redis_host, port='6379')
```

**Core module (blueprint)**

```
from flask import Blueprint

core = Blueprint('core', __name__, template_folder='templates')

from . import views
```

**core.views**

```
@core.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    if current_user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect(url_for('core.index'))
    form = LoginForm()
    print('------ {0}'.format(form.csrf_token))
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        user = User.query.filter_by(username=form.username.data).first()
        if user is None or not user.check_password(form.password.data):
            flash('Incorrect Username or Password')
            return redirect(url_for('core.login'))
        login_user(user, remember=form.remember_me.data)
        next_page = request.args.get('next')
        if not next_page or url_parse(next_page).netloc != '':
            next_page = url_for('core.index')
        return redirect(next_page)
    return render_template('login.html', title='Sign In', form=form)
```

I don't really know what to try now. The CSRF token is there, but it keeps telling me its missing?

Comment: Is your server running HTTPS? Because you have set SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE and that means any cookies are sent only through secure channel. And csrf token is validated against the value stored in session. See https://github.com/lepture/flask-wtf/issues/76